# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' from same server

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I have a problem with CORS policy. Trying access to php file in the same server of ajax code, but have the CORS error.

```
            await $.ajax({
                        url: '/includes/paystripe.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: {api_key_stripe: api_key_stripe, customer_id:customer_id},
                        success: function(data){                              

                        }
                    });
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.subDomain.domain.com/includes/paystripe.php' (redirected from 'https://subDomain.domain.com/includes/paystripe.php') from origin 'https://subDomain.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

If I work on localhost, don't have this problem, it's posible poblem with server config?

EDIT:
If I put headers on paystripe.php get a 500 error (only on server, not on localhost):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

Comment: `crossDomain: true` probably doesn't do what you think it does. This forces a cross-domain request even when it wasn't cross-domain to begin with. Probably this is unhelpful, at best.

Comment: I try this on ajax, but doesn't work..

Comment: Ok. But still, even if it doesn't solve this specific issue you don't really need it.

Comment: Anyway can you post the full error message you're seeing please, that will hopefully make things a bit clearer for everyone.

Comment: The  full error message is in post:
Access to XMLHttpRequest...

Comment: ok sorry it wasn't easily visible before.

Comment: Anyway, I note a subdomain in the URL. As far as CORS is concerned, a subdomain counts as a separate origin. Therefore the PHP needs to enable CORS, if the AJAX request is going from the domain to the subdomain.

Comment: Don't worry, and thx! :)

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error when you add that PHP code, please tell us the underlying PHP exception which resulted in the 500.